# In google sheet web app, how do i remove the numbering that appears on the top of each row? some products are also not filtering

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I remove the numbering on the top of each row when I filter the products? The code is also not displaying some of the products when I select the category and sub-category. Can you help? Here is the code

```
function getCategories() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
var categories = [];
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var category = data[i][0];
  if (categories.indexOf(category) == -1) {
    categories.push(category);
  }
}
  return categories;
}

function getSubCategories(category) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
var subCategories = [];
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
var rowCategory = data[i][0];
var subCategory = data[i][1];
if (rowCategory == category && subCategories.indexOf(subCategory) == -1) {
  subCategories.push(subCategory);
 }
}
   return subCategories;
 }

function filterProducts(category, subCategory) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var filteredData = data.filter(function(row) {
  return row[0] == category && row[1] == subCategory;
});
  return filteredData;
}

function doGet() {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
template.categories = getCategories();
return template.evaluate().setTitle('Product Filter');
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
 }
```

Here is the HTML code. When the web app runs,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <base target="_top">
            <script>
      function updateSubCategories() {
        var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(subCategories) {
          var subCategoryDropdown = document.getElementById('sub-category');
          subCategoryDropdown.innerHTML = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < subCategories.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = subCategories[i];
            option.text = subCategories[i];
            subCategoryDropdown.appendChild(option);
          }
        }).getSubCategories(category);
      }
     
      function filterProducts() {
        var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
        var subCategory = document.getElementById('sub-category').value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(filteredData) {
          var productTable = document.getElementById('product-table');
          productTable.innerHTML = '';
          var headers = Object.keys(filteredData[0]); // get the keys of the first row as 
          column headers
          var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
          for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
            headerCell.textContent = headers[i];
            headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
          }
          productTable.appendChild(headerRow);
          for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) { // changed starting index to 0
            var row = filteredData[i];
            var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) { // loop through headers to get the 
            values for the row
              var tableCell = document.createElement('td');
              tableCell.textContent = row[headers[j]];
              tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
            }
            productTable.appendChild(tableRow);
          }
        }).filterProducts(category, subCategory);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Product Filter</h1>
    <label for="category">Category:</label>
    <select id="category" onchange="updateSubCategories()">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?= categories[i] ?>"><?= categories[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
    </select>
    <label for="sub-category">Sub-Category:</label>
    <select id="sub-category" onchange="filterProducts()">
    </select>
    <table id="product-table">
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The pictures below will show you what is happening.

[image: Products]    [image: product 1]

This is the Google sheets.

[image: Google sheets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the function `filterProducts` of Google Apps Script returns an array like `[['sample1', 'sample2',,,,],,,]`. And, at the function `filterProducts` of Javascript, `var headers = Object.keys(filteredData[0]);` is used as the header. In this case, the header is an array like `['0', '1',,,]`. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue of `the numbering on the top of each row when I filter the products`. When you want to remove this, please modify it as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, `filterProducts` of Javascript is modified as follows.

```js
function filterProducts() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
  var subCategory = document.getElementById('sub-category').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(filteredData) {
    var productTable = document.getElementById('product-table');
    productTable.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
      var row = filteredData[i];
      var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { 
        var tableCell = document.createElement('td');
        tableCell.textContent = row[j];
        tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
      }
      productTable.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
  }).filterProducts(category, subCategory);
}
```

- By this modification, the number row of the top row is removed.

#### Modified script 2:

At "Modified script 1", your question of `How do I remove the numbering on the top of each row when I filter the products?` is directly achieved. But, if you want to add the header row of the Spreadsheet, how about the following modification? I'm not sure about your actual expected result. So, I would like to propose this as another approach. Please select one of them.

In this case, how about modifying Javascript and Google Apps Script as follows?

##### Javascript:

Please modify `filterProducts` of your Javascript as follows.

```js
function filterProducts() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
  var subCategory = document.getElementById('sub-category').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(filteredData) {
    var [headers, ...filteredData] = filteredData;
    var productTable = document.getElementById('product-table');
    productTable.innerHTML = '';
    var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
      headerCell.textContent = headers[i];
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
    }
    productTable.appendChild(headerRow);
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
      var row = filteredData[i];
      var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { 
        var tableCell = document.createElement('td');
        tableCell.textContent = row[j];
        tableRow.appendChild(tableCell);
      }
      productTable.appendChild(tableRow);
    }
  }).filterProducts(category, subCategory);
}
```

##### Google Apps Script:

Please modify `filterProducts` of your Google Apps Script as follows.

```js
function filterProducts(category, subCategory) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Product");
  var [headers, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = data.filter(function (row) {
    return row[0] == category && row[1] == subCategory;
  });
  return [headers, ...filteredData];
}
```

- By this modification, the rows including the header row are shown.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike. That fixed the first problem. Would you also know why the filter does not display other products like i showed in the second picture above?

Comment: @lamin suso Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Would you also know why the filter does not display other products like i showed in the second picture above?`, I cannot understand your new question. I think that this is due to my poor English kill. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: do you see the pictures I added? The first one shows the Samsung phones, but when I select the watch, it does not show the watch. Do you know why?

Comment: @lamin suso I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply `do you see the pictures I added? The first one shows the Samsung phones, but when I select the watch, it does not show the watch. Do you know why?`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. But, if you want an answer to your new question soon, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon.

Comment: No problem, I will post it as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: @lamin Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. When I saw your new question and I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution.